# Terminology Q: "algebraic argument"

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, linear-programming

Reading some papers on (transportation problem type) operations research  I find authors referring to proofs that use "purely algebraic arguments," sometimes as opposed to "combinatorial arguments."

Can you help me understand what are they trying to convey? for instance, what is it that makes showing non-emptiness of a polytope through a constructive algorithm "not an algebraic argument"? would fixed point theorem or separating hyperplane arguments be considered algebraic or not?

thanks in advance